# Bootstrap subtheme move main navigation

Tags: navigation, theming

I have a sub theme based off Bootstrap and my current nav bar look like this

[image]

My goal is to move the menu (Home ... contact) to appear underneath the slogan when the page is larger than 768px as it is the breakpoint when it turns into a burger button and appears on the right. I was trying to play around with the css and the `page.tpl.php`, but no results there. This is the first time I've used Bootstrap with Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint in your LESS/CSS (ideally you're using LESS or SASS with bootstrap, but anyway) and I'd probably make the slogan absolute position and use the `top` property as suggested by @Darvanen like this:

```
    /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
        div.slogan {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }
        div#main-menu {
            margin-top: 30px; // Depends on the size of the slogan div
        }
    }
```

You might need to experiment with the positioning of the menu div, like make it `position: relative;`.

For more see the excellent bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

To move things around like that you will either need to use the CSS `top` property within your CSS or SASS file(s), or move it around with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully modified page.tpl.php file and completely replaced the header section with -

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="text-muted">
      <a class="logo" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
      </a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <nav role="navigation">
              <?php if (!empty($primary_nav)): ?>
                <?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if (!empty($secondary_nav)): ?>
                <?php print render($secondary_nav); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```